# how to uncommit all files from remote repository

Tags: git, github

I have a branch that I need delete all files from remote repository and turn it untracked files, how can I do this?
I tried to use `git rm` but it just deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git rm -r --cached .`

That would remove the files from the index (marking them for deletion in the `git status` output), but not from the disk.